# Pre-emptive Water Heater Replacement

Tags: water-heater

An old ground-floor office has an old electric water heater.  The building was built in 1994, so the water heater's age could be ~25 years. The tank / office has been unused for the last 8 years.

What is the decision making process to determine if it makes sense to replace the water heater now or wait until it fails (leaks or stops producing hot water)?

Comment: Can you shut it off and pull the anode out for inspection?

Comment: I can certainly shut the heater off.  If I can inspect the anode I'll publish more details in the OP.  This video makes it seem easy enough: https://youtu.be/2IUNIUZz4Os

Answer (score 2):

Cost of replacing it now vs cost of replacing it later plus cost of cleaning up from its failure (anywhere from nothing to a whole lot). Throw in some kind of likelihood of it failing.

If it's a commercial property, just replace it now. If residential, a home inspector or plumber could probably take a look and give an estimate on likelihood of failure. Any corrosion, strange sounds, etc and I'd just replace it now.

Comment: I'd replace it regardless if commercial or residential. Water heaters typically only have a lifespan of 7-12 years and one that old could fail any day. I wouldn't take the chance.

Comment: @MicahMontoya -- pulling the anode gives very good insight into what's going on inside the tank, and it's very possible under some water conditions for a heater to "passivate" and survive for ages

Answer (score 0):

I have seen water heaters last longer when regular annode replacements and flushing the sediment were regularly done. The annode is the life extender of the tank if this is changed prior to it totally being consumed the tank may last another 10 years. In my area if you change to one of the new water heaters purchased from the power company they give a rebate for the cost of the unit 40 gallon, with larger water heaters than 40 gallon the rebate is not as high so if your power company has a rebate like that I might do it now, but if no rebate I would check the annode and replace , then flush the sediment.